# C# asp.net - Can't replace german char in string

Tags: c#, replace

I have in table German football teams and one of them is `Köln`, but I want to change in `Koln` to create link to the club. I tried this, but it doesn't appear to change the `ö` into an `o`:

```
GridViewUzaTabela.Rows[k].Cells[2].Text = GridViewUzaTabela.Rows[k]              
                     .Cells[2].Text.Replace(" ", String.Empty).Replace("ö", "o")
```

`Replace(" ", String.Empty)` - this works

`Replace("ö", "o")` - this doesn't work

Comment: can you try Replace('ö', 'o'), single quotes. I think char replace supports unicode and string does not.

Comment: It appears you've been able to resolve the problem yourself. For the benefit of future visitors, you might consider detailing the steps you took to determine the what the actual problem was and the resolution you found in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try method overload that uses Char

```
text.Replace('ö','o')
```

Comment: Strange. This code does exactly what you need: Debug.Log("fasö1 1ö23".Replace(" ",string.Empty).Replace('ö','o')); Result: "faso11o23".

Comment: I have in table German football teams and one of them is Köln and I want to change in Koln because I create link of club

Comment: Just tried my code with word "Köln". It works. Show me how you use this code

Comment: problem was with html decode because I use data from database

Comment: GridViewUzaTabela.Rows[k].Cells[2].Text = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(GridViewUzaTabela.Rows[k].Cells[2].Text); 
                    GridViewUzaTabela.Rows[k].Cells[2].Text = GridViewUzaTabela.Rows[k].Cells[2].Text.Replace("ö","o");                  now it works

Comment: Amazing. Then It would be great if you could mark my answer as correct, if it was helpful for you.

Comment: Thank You Utamaru for your time. If I mark your answer as correct it can confuse some other people with the same problem what I had